# Claws Mail SMTP issue; cannot send

Tags: email, smtp, imap

I am abandoning Thunderbird after it has slowly become a terrible, terrible piece of software for me. I have gotten everything set up with Claws, except sending. There are no official forums for this program, so I've been left to explore other options... here.

Below is the log message I get when trying to send a message in Claws mail. I cannot see anything wrong off the top of my head, except that I have no idea what a NOOP is. I have replaced the server information for the sake of privacy.

```
* Account 'XXX@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX': Connecting to IMAP4 server: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:143...
[16:23:27] IMAP4< * OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR SORT THREAD=REFERENCES MULTIAPPEND UNSELECT LITERAL+ IDLE CHILDREN NAMESPACE LOGIN-REFERRALS UIDPLUS LIST-EXTENDED I18NLEVEL=1 STARTTLS LOGINDISABLED] Dovecot ready. 
* IMAP connection is un-authenticated
[16:23:27] IMAP4> 1 CAPABILITY 
[16:23:27] IMAP4< * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR SORT THREAD=REFERENCES MULTIAPPEND UNSELECT LITERAL+ IDLE CHILDREN NAMESPACE LOGIN-REFERRALS UIDPLUS LIST-EXTENDED I18NLEVEL=1 STARTTLS LOGINDISABLED 
[16:23:27] IMAP4< 1 OK Capability completed. 
** Server requires TLS to log in.
[16:23:27] IMAP4> 2 STARTTLS 
[16:23:27] IMAP4< 2 OK Begin TLS negotiation now. 
[16:23:27] IMAP4> 3 CAPABILITY 
[16:23:27] IMAP4< * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR SORT THREAD=REFERENCES MULTIAPPEND UNSELECT LITERAL+ IDLE CHILDREN NAMESPACE LOGIN-REFERRALS UIDPLUS LIST-EXTENDED I18NLEVEL=1 AUTH=PLAIN 
[16:23:27] IMAP4< 3 OK Capability completed. 
[16:23:27] IMAP4> Logging XXX to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX using LOGIN
[16:23:27] IMAP4< Logged in.
[16:23:27] IMAP4< Login to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX successful
[16:23:27] IMAP4> 5 LIST "" "" 
[16:23:27] IMAP4< * LIST (\Noselect) "/" "" 
[16:23:27] IMAP4< 5 OK List completed. 
[16:23:27] IMAP4> 6 SELECT Queue 
[16:23:28] IMAP4< * FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft) 
[16:23:28] IMAP4< * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft \*)] Flags permitted. 
[16:23:28] IMAP4< * 0 EXISTS 
[16:23:28] IMAP4< * 0 RECENT 
[16:23:28] IMAP4< * OK [UIDVALIDITY 1290097352] UIDs valid 
[16:23:28] IMAP4< * OK [UIDNEXT 9] Predicted next UID 
[16:23:28] IMAP4< 6 OK [READ-WRITE] Select completed. 
[16:23:28] IMAP4- [fetching UIDs...]
[16:23:28] IMAP4> 7 UID FETCH 1:* (UID) 
[16:23:28] IMAP4< 7 OK Fetch completed. 
[16:23:28] IMAP4> 8 APPEND Queue (\Seen) {690} 
[16:23:28] IMAP4< + OK 
[16:23:28] IMAP4> [data - 692 bytes]
[16:23:28] IMAP4< [APPEND data - 73 bytes]
[16:23:28] IMAP4> 9 NOOP 
[16:23:28] IMAP4< 9 OK NOOP completed. 
[16:23:28] IMAP4> 10 UID STORE 9 +FLAGS.SILENT (\Seen) 
[16:23:28] IMAP4< 10 OK Store completed. 
* Account 'XXX@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX': Connecting to SMTP server: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:25...
[16:23:28] IMAP4> 11 UID STORE 9 +FLAGS.SILENT (\Deleted) 
[16:23:28] IMAP4< 11 OK Store completed. 
[16:23:28] IMAP4> 12 EXPUNGE 
[16:23:28] IMAP4< * 1 EXPUNGE 
[16:23:28] IMAP4< * 0 RECENT 
[16:23:28] IMAP4< 12 OK Expunge completed. 
[16:23:28] IMAP4- [fetching UIDs...]
[16:23:28] IMAP4> 13 UID FETCH 1:* (UID) 
[16:23:28] IMAP4< 13 OK Fetch completed. 
[16:24:27] IMAP4> 14 NOOP 
[16:24:28] IMAP4< 14 OK NOOP completed.
```

Comment: maybe not a claws issue...are you sure you had port 25 for the outgoing server in thunderbird? many providers block this port outgoing nowadays and force you to use 587 instead. verify with telnet maybe?

Comment: I did have port 25 in thunderbird, I have the settings open in front of me. I will try port 587, however.

Comment: also make sure "smtp authentication" is enabled in the send options of your account. and if neither makes a difference it would be helpful to know what error message you actually get when sending. your log only shows the "connecting " part of the smtp transaction, all the rest is IMAP and not related to sending.

Comment: The error is "an error happened during SMTP session." and something about trying to resend from the main menu using "send queued messages" (this option is not available)

And that log is the entire available log. I included the whole thing.

Comment: without a real error message we (or at least I) can only guess. one thing that comes to mind is verifying the SSL settings (STARTTLS / SSL) for the outgoing account. also make sure no firewall/local antivirus interferes with your connection. if that doesn't help it would be helpful if you can get the error message from the server side if you are/know the admin there.

Comment: I'll see if there are any logs available to me aside from what I've already provided.

Comment: The log you have pasted here is an IMAP log, which is only for reading mail.  The SMTP log for sending mail (if there is one) must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a response to one part of your question - as has been said in comments, the log you've shown is only for IMAP, and  you need to look for the SMTP logs in order for anybody to help you with sending.

The question that I can answer, however, is what the NOOP command does. It literally does nothing; it is sort for "no operation", and its only purpose is to keep the IMAP connection open. If you don't send any data through a TCP connection, it will be shut down by either the server or the client computer after a specific time, since one of them will consider it non-active. Sending NOOP and getting a reply to it will keep that from happening.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem with my organisation's gmail account. It turns out I forgot to enable SMTP authentication in account settings -> Account -> Send -> Authentication. Claws would automatically setup that part for standard gmail account.

Not sure if this is your problem but you may want to check that.

Comment: That is, if you still need this 5 years later.

Answer (score 0):

This took some time of figure - re send. (these are the settings that worked for my gmail accounts)

Key Claws Settings for Gmail IMAP accounts created 2019.

One: Gmail: Settings > Forwarding and POP/IMAP > Enable IMAP

Two: Gmail: Turn on -> Allow less secure Apps (if this setting is off Claws will not receive or send) -> Open Gmail in browser and click Account Icon Circle to right of hamburger circle icon > click [Google Account] button > Security > Less secure app access > toggle on

Three: Claws

It is assumed the user has set up the Gmail account in Claws but some features are not working.

Obvious settings have been omitted.

To edit properties -> Configuration > Edit Account > Edit

BASIC:
Server for receiving: imap.gmail.com //
SMTP server(send): smtp.gmail.com

RECEIVE:
Authentication ..: [Automatic] //
Filter messages ..: [ticked] //
Allow filtering ..: [ticked] //
'Get mail'...: [ticked]

SEND:
Add user agent header: [ticked] //
Authentication: (SMTP AUTH) > [Automatic]

SSL/TLS:
IMAP - USE SSL/TLS //
Send(SMTP) - USE SSL/TLS // 
Automatically accept valid ......: [ticked] //
Use non-blocking SSL/TLS..: ......: [ticked]

ADVANCED:
SMTP[465] (note: 587 did not work) //
IMAP port [933]

See this - Claws refuses to send mail, and says the queue folder cannot be found - https://www.claws-mail.org/faq/index.php/Installation_and_Configuration#Claws_refuses_to_send_mail.2C_and_says_the_queue_folder_cannot_be_found

If this Folder is not created by default then create it and assign it as below //
Put queued message in - [#imap/JH - AM/Queue]

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue with my organization's Domain accounts. The solution is to enable SMTP authentication in account settings -> Account -> Send -> Authentication then enter the userID and password. Then under SSL/TLS check use SSL/TLS on both IMAP and SMTP , then check the two boxes under advanced for SMTP and IMAP ports. Also, don't forget under basic to set protocol to IMAP and enter the details.

Answer (score -3):

Be sure you are at rev 3.11.1 of claws-mail. If not try terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:claws-mail &&
sudo apt-get update &&
sudo apt-get install claws-mail
```

On my system, the 3.11.1 install replaced current install. Bring claws-mail up, check the rev, go to configuration>preferences

tab (basic) 
  box1 'yourname', box2 'yourname', box 3 'uremailaddr', box4 empty     POP3 autoconfig, server 'pop.urserver.com', SMTP  server 'smtp.urserver.com', userid 'youremail', password 'yourpassword'

tab (receive) box1 empty, box 2 checked, box 3 empty, box 4,5,6 checked

Tab (send) box1 checked, box2 empty, box3 checked, box4 empty, box5 checked (smtp auth automatic, uid empty, passwd empty), box 6 empty

tabs compose, privacy and advanced default

tab (SSL) POP3 circ1 cked, circ2 empty, circ3 empty,
          Send (SMTP) circ1 empty, circ2 cked, circ3 empty,
          2 ck boxes at bottom checked

Tab Advanced default. SMTP port and POP3 port dependent on provider.

worked for me using Linux mint 17.